# c# garbage collection not work .netframework 4 and above

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, destructor

this code works fine with netfarmework 3.5 but when i change the version to netframework 4 and 4.5 garbage collector not collect the object and destructor nut runs

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("count=" + Employee.count);
        Employee e1 = new Employee("test", "test");
        e1 = null;
        //force garbage collection
        GC.Collect();
        //wait until collection complete
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine("after GC count= " + Employee.count);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

and this is class

```
class Employee
{
    public static int count;
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    //constructor
    public Employee(string fname, string lname)
    {
        firstName = fname;
        lastName = lname;
        ++count;
        Console.WriteLine("constructor count= "+count);
    }
    //destructor
    ~Employee()
    {

        --count;
        Console.WriteLine("destructor count= " + count);
    }


}
```

Comment: Raymond Chen's [Everybody thinks about Garbage Collection the wrong way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203): "A correctly-written program cannot assume that finalizers will ever run at any point prior to program termination... it cannot even assume that finalizers will run when the program terminates"

Comment: If you want a deterministic life-cycle (not the same thing as collection, note): you should be using `IDisposable`; if you don't want deterministic: stop assuming that you know when things "should" be collected. The GC decides that, not you.

Comment: Yes it does work. Why are you breaking it?

Comment: not that it matters, but if this is intended to be accurate, you should really use `Interlocked.Increment`/`Decrement` here, not `++`/`--`